# Why beatifulsoup returns empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

in my code everything works just fine but when I try to get the price of the product it keeps returning empty list, i have tried soup.select, find and findAll but all return None or empty list.

selector for the price: '#product-price > div > span:nth-child(2) > span.current-price-container > span.current-price'

try to paste the selcetor in the console after you enter the website https://www.asos.com/search/?q=jordan

the console will output the price but my code won't.

check line 36

```
import requests
from bs4 import beautifulsoup

class Scraper:

    def __init__(self):  
        self.headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 123.1.0.26.115 (iPhone11,8; iOS 13_3; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 190542906)",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "X-IG-Capabilities": "3brTvw==",
            "X-IG-Connection-Type": "WIFI",
        }
        self.KEYWORDS = [
            "jordan", "jordan 1", "air jordan", "jordan 3", "jordan 4", "jordan 5", "jordan 6", "dunk", "sb dunk",
            "dunk high", "dunk low",
            "air force", "air force 1", "blazer", "Yeezy", "Travis", "Travis Scott", "Off White", "jordan 1 low",
            "jordan low", "Peso", "virgil", "kanye",
            "kanye west", "powerphase", "university", "grape", "varsity", "jordan 1 mid", "jordan mid", "light grey",
            "shattered", "chicago", "tie dye",
            "dunk low", "air max 90", "air max", "Fear of god", "fog", "supreme", "bape", "off-white"
        ]
    def GetPage(self):
        
        self.request = requests.get('https://www.asos.com/search/?q=jordan', headers=self.headers)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.request.text, 'html.parser')
        self.GetProductLinks()

    def ScrapProduct(self):
        for link in self.ProductsLinks:
            page = requests.get(link, headers=self.headers)
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            self.PRODUCT_NAME = self.soup.select('#aside-content > div.product-hero > h1')
            self.PRODUCT_PRICE = self.soup.select('#product-price > div > span:nth-child(2) > span.current-price-container > span.current-price') #MY PROBLEM IS HERE
            # self.PRODUCT_COLOR = self.soup.select('#product-colour > section > div > div > span')

            print(self.PRODUCT_NAME, self.PRODUCT_PRICE)
        

    def GetProductLinks(self):
        self.FindProducts = self.soup.select('#plp > div > div._3-pwX1m > div > div._3pQmLlY > section > article > a')
        self.ProductsLinks = []
        for product in self.FindProducts:
            self.ProductsLinks.append(product['href'])
        self.ScrapProduct()


Scraper = Scraper()
Scraper.GetPage()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.
Your posted code is not minimal.  You haven't traced the values that contribute to the problem.  This is not yet ready for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. Don't rely on unreadable css selectors, but rather on the names attributes. The following code has to be adapted :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0"}
url = "https://www.asos.com/search/?q=jordan"
resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs(resp.content)
articles = list(soup.find_all("article", attrs={"data-auto-id":True}))

descriptions = [article.find("div", attrs={"data-auto-id":True}).text for article in articles]
prices = [article.find("span", attrs={"data-auto-id":True}).text for article in articles]

for el in zip(descriptions, prices):
    print(el)

# renvoi
#    ('Nike Jordan Jumpman t-shirt in white', '£19.95')
#    ('Nike Jordan Jumpman shorts in black', '£31.95')
#    ('Nike Jordan Jumpman large logo t-shirt in grey', '£24.95')
#    ....
```

Be careful sometimes, there is a need to load several pages consider adding "page" in your url as follows :
https://www.asos.com/search/?page=2&q=jordan